# What dynamical system could this $\dot y = \alpha(y-\lambda), y\geq \lambda$ equation describe?

Tags: electric-circuits, differential-equations, linear-systems

Just out of curiosity, can anyone identify electrical, mechanical, chemical, etc process that is governed by a differential equation of the form

$$\dot y = \alpha(y-\lambda), y\geq \lambda$$

where $\alpha, \lambda$ are rate variables.

The only term that is confusing me is the $\lambda$ factor. I cannot recall ever seeing a differential equation that has a threshold factor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example in astrophysics is the [radiative transport equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiative_transfer), which, in its most simple form, is
$$
\frac{dI_\nu}{ds}=- I_\nu+S_\nu
$$
with $I_\nu$ the frequency-dependent intensity, $s$ the path length, and $S_\nu$ a source term (e.g., the Planck function).

If $S_\nu>I_\nu$ then the RHS is positive and $I_\nu$ increases. Conversely, if $S_\nu<I_\nu$ then the RHS gets more negative and $I_\nu$ decreases. Either way, it converges to $I_\nu= S_\nu$.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very generic system, because:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\dot y}{y - \lambda} &= \alpha \\
ln(y-\lambda) &= \alpha t + \ln C\\
y &= \lambda + C e^{\alpha t}
\end{align}$$

Which is related to an arbitrary exponential function by a shift of the y coordinate.  So, any exponential growth can be described by this equation.

of course, a more straightforward way of seeing this would be to define $z = y - \lambda$, and then your equation becomes

$${\dot z} = \alpha z$$

which is obviously just a plain exponential.